# ms teams custom app starting a chat session with a bot

Tags: bots, microsoft-teams

I'm building a teams app that contains some tabs and a bot.
Is it possible to, when an action is performed on a tab (i.e. clicking a button), initialize automatically a chat with the bot, or send a specific message?

Tks

Comment: Can you explain a bit more detail what you're trying to do? When the user installs the app, they will automatically install the bot at the same time, and therefore automatically initialize the chat...

Comment: The idea is on the tab to manage some information. When the user inserts a new record, the bot will ask a question to gather more information. Probably there's many ways to achieve this, I'm just exploring the options. Right now I just want to figure out if I can, after that record is inserted, to send a confirmation card and trigger an action for the bot.

Comment: Ah ok, now I get it. Answer below

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments above, what you're looking to do is implement "pro-active" messaging, where the bot itself initiates the conversation. It's definitely possible, and you can read more to get started [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-proactive-messaging). The most important thing to know is that your user has to have installed the bot already, to get a "conversation context", but if they've installed the app, which includes the bot, to get the tab, then you're fine. You need to get some variables when they *do* install the app, which you hook into the `conversationUpdate` event to get access to. Give it a go and let me know if you have specific questions, here on SOverflow.